# How to configure FIWARE Components to avoid AZF domain not created for application response

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wilma, fiware-keyrock

Summary of the question: How can we let the FIWARE IdM Keyrock and the FIWARE Authzforce set properly the AZF domains, thus without getting "AZF domain not created for application XYZ" response?

I'm trying to configure a server with FIWARE Orion, FIWARE PepProxy Wilma, FIWARE IdM Keyrock, FIWARE Authzforce properly.
I arrived at the point in which the first 3 components work properly and interact with each other, but now I'm trying to insert autorization and I obtain the following error:
`AZF domain not created for application`.
I've already tried all the solutions presented at the following links but no one works:

- https://fiware-pep-proxy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/#level-2-basic-authorization
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coxFQEY0_So
- [How to configure the Fiware PEP WILMA proxy to use a Keyrock and Orion instance on my own servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628531/how-to-configure-the-fiware-pep-wilma-proxy-to-use-a-keyrock-and-orion-instance/31169049#31169049)
- [Fiware IDM+AuthZForce+PEP-Proxy-Wilma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017142/fiware-idmauthzforcepep-proxy-wilma/45018719#45018719)
- [Fiware - how to connect PEP proxy to Orion and configure both with HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360026/fiware-how-to-connect-pep-proxy-to-orion-and-configure-both-with-https)
- [Fiware AuthZForce error: "AZF domain not created for application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714175/fiware-authzforce-error-azf-domain-not-created-for-application)
- [AuthZForce Security Level 2: Basic Authorization error "AZF domain not created for application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606813/authzforce-security-level-2-basic-authorization-error-azf-domain-not-created-f)
- https://www.slideshare.net/daltoncezane/integrating-fiware-orion-keyrock-and-wilma
- [“AZF domain not created for application” AuthZforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513118/azf-domain-not-created-for-application-authzforce)
- [Fiware AuthZForce error: "AZF domain not created for application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714175/fiware-authzforce-error-azf-domain-not-created-for-application)
- [Fiware suitable Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622048/fiware-suitable-components)
- https://www.slideshare.net/FI-WARE/adding-identity-management-and-access-control-to-your-app-70523086
- [Official documentation not usable because refers to (maybe) old python version of IdM](https://authzforce-ce-fiware.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UserAndProgrammersGuide.html#integration-with-the-idm-and-pep-proxy-ges-e-g-for-oauth)

In the following you can find the instructions to reproduce my scenario:

1. Install Orion by using the Docker container

   - Create a directory on your system on which to work (for example, `/home/fiware-orion-docker`).
   - Create a new file called `docker-compose.yml` inside your directory with the following contents:

   ```
        mongo:
            image: mongo:3.4
            command: --nojournal
        orion:
            image: fiware/orion
            links:
                - mongo
            ports:
                - "1026:1026"
            command: -dbhost mongo -logLevel DEBUG
            dns:
                - 208.67.222.222
                - 208.67.220.220
   ```

   - PAY ATTENTION: without the DNS it will never send notifications!!!
   - PAY ATTENTION 2 ([source](https://svenv.nl/unixandlinux/dockerufw/) ): Connections from docker containers get routed into the (iptables) FORWARD chain, this needs to be configured to allow connections through it. The default is to DROP the connections. Thus if you use a firewall you have to change it:

     - `sudo nano /etc/default/ufw`
     - Set DEFAULTFORWARDPOLICY to “ACCEPT”.
           
           `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`
     - Save the file.
     - Reload ufw
           
           `sudo ufw reload`
   - Within the directory you created, type the following command in the command line: `sudo docker-compose up -d`.
   - After a few seconds you should have your Context Broker running and listening on port `1026`.
   - Check that everything works with
          `curl localhost:1026/version`
2. Install FIWARE IdM Keyrock (used for authentication over the Orion Context Broker):
   https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm

   - WARNING -1: (if the next command doesn't work: 
     `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful stable"` )
   - WARNING 0: if you have a firewall: **DISABLE IT**, otherwise docker-compose will not work
   - sudo apt-get install docker-compose
   - mkdir fiware-idm
   - cd fiware-idm
   - create docker-compose.yml
     `nano docker-compose.yml`

   ```
       version: "3.5"
   services:
       keyrock:
           image: fiware/idm:7.6.0
           container_name: fiware-keyrock
           hostname: keyrock
           networks:
               default:
                   ipv4_address: 172.18.1.5
           depends_on:
               - mysql-db
           ports:
               - "3000:3000"
           environment:
               - DEBUG=idm:*
               - IDM_DB_HOST=mysql-db
               - IDM_HOST=http://localhost:3000
               - IDM_PORT=3000
               # Development use only
               # Use Docker Secrets for Sensitive Data
               - IDM_DB_PASS=secret
               - IDM_DB_USER=root
               - IDM_ADMIN_USER=admin
               - IDM_ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@test.com
               - IDM_ADMIN_PASS=1234

       mysql-db:
           restart: always
           image: mysql:5.7
           hostname: mysql-db
           container_name: db-mysql
           expose:
               - "3306"
           ports:
               - "3306:3306"
           networks:
               default:
                   ipv4_address: 172.18.1.6
           environment:
               # Development use only
               # Use Docker Secrets for Sensitive Data
               - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
               - "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.18.1.5"
           volumes:
               - mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql

   networks:
       default:
           ipam:
               config:
                   - subnet: 172.18.1.0/24
   volumes:
       mysql-db: ~
   ```

   - `sudo docker-compose up -d` (This will automatically download the two images and run the IdM Keyrock service. (-d is used to run it in background)).
   - Now you should be able to access the Identity Management tool through the website http://localhost:3000

     - username: `admin@test.com`
     - password: `1234`
   - Register a new user and enable it through the interface
   - Then use the GUI to:

     - Create an "Organization" (e.g., ORGANIZ1)
     - Create an "application"

       - Step 1:

         ```
         Name: Orion Idm
         Description: Orion Idm
         URL: http://localhost
         Callback URL: http://localhost
         Grant Type: Authorization Code, Implicit, Resource Owner Password, Client Credentials, Refresh Token
         Provider: newuser
         ```
       - Step 2: leave empty
       - Step 3: choose "Provider"
       - Step 4:

         - click on "OAuth2 Credentials" and take notes of "Client ID" (94480bc9-43e8-4c15-ad45-0bb227e42e63) and "Client Secret" (4f6ye5y7-b90d-473a-3rr7-ea2f6dd43246)
         - Click on "PEP Proxy" and then on "Register a new PEP Proxy"
         - take notes of "Application Id" (94480bc9-43e8-4c15-ad45-0bb227e42e63), "Pep Proxy Username" (pep_proxy_dad356d2-dasa-4f95-a9hf-9ab06tccf929), and "Pep Proxy Password" (pep_proxy_a33667ec-57y1-498k-85aa-ef77ue5f6234)
         - Click on "Authorize" (Users) and authorize all the existing users with both roles (Purchaser and Provider for all the options)
         - Click on "Authorize" (Organizations) and authorize all the existing organizations with both roles (Purchaser and Provider for all the options)
3. Install the FIWARE Authzforce

   - `sudo docker pull authzforce/server:latest` (latest was 8.1.0 at the moment of writing)
   - `sudo docker run -d -p 8085:8080 --name authzforce_server authzforce/server`
4. Install the FIWARE PEP Proxy Wilma (used to enable https and authentication for Orion):

   - git clone https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy.git
   - cd fiware-pep-proxy
   - cp config.js.template config.js
   - nano config.js

   ```
   var config = {};

       // Used only if https is disabled
       config.pep_port = 5056;
       config.https = undefined

       config.idm = {
           host: 'localhost',
           port: 3000,
           ssl: false
       }

       config.app = {
           host: 'localhost',
           port: '1026',
           ssl: false // Use true if the app server listens in https
       }

       config.response_type = 'code';

       // Credentials obtained when registering PEP Proxy in app_id in Account Portal
       config.pep = {
           app_id: '91180bc9-43e8-4c14-ad45-0bb117e42e63',
           username: 'pep_proxy_dad356d2-dasa-4f95-a9hf-9ab06tccf929',
           password: 'pep_proxy_a33667ec-57y1-498k-85aa-ef77ue5f6234',
           trusted_apps : []
       }

       // in seconds
       config.cache_time = 300;

       // list of paths that will not check authentication/authorization
       // example: ['/public/*', '/static/css/']
       config.public_paths = [];

       config.magic_key = undefined;

       module.exports = config;

       config.authorization = {
           enabled: true,
           pdp: 'authzforce',      // idm|authzforce  
           azf: {
               protocol: 'http',
               host: 'localhost',
               port: 8085,
               custom_policy: undefined, // use undefined to default policy checks (HTTP verb + path).
           } 
       }
   ```

   - install all the dependencies
     `npm install`
   - run the proxy
     `sudo node server`
5. Create a user role:
   Reconnect to the IdM `http://localhost:3000`:

   - click on your application
   - click on `Manage rules` at the top of the page
   - click on the `+` button near Roles

     - Name: "trial"
   - Save
   - click on the `+` button near Permission

     - Permission Name: trial1
     - Description: trial1
     - HTTP action: GET
     - Resource: version
   - Save
   - come back to the application
   - Click on "Authorize" near "Authorized users"
   - Assign the "trial" role to your user
6. Now use PostMan to get a token:

   - connect to localhost:3000/oauth2/token and send the following parameters

     - Body:
     - username:
     - password:
     - grant_type: password
     - Header:
     - Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     - Authorization: BASIC
   - take note of the obtained `access_token`
7. Try to connect to Orion though http://localhost:5056/version with the following parameters:

   - Header:

     - X-auth-token:
8. You will obtain the following response:
   `AZF domain not created for application 91180bc9-43e8-4c14-ad45-0bb117e42e63`

Comment: Your architecture matches the example in the [XACML-Access-Rules](https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.XACML-Access-Rules) tutorial. Could you check the docker-compose in the example. It may be the case that you need to **generate** the authzforce `<PolicySet>` by making a whitespace change in **Keyrock** first.

Comment: You can also look at the [Administrating-XACML](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Administrating-XACML) tutorial

Comment: I have checked the docker-compose file and I've also tried to execute the tutorial without any change, but, in both the circumstances I obtain the error described here:
[https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.XACML-Access-Rules/issues/2](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.XACML-Access-Rules/issues/2)

Comment: The issue #2 was mainly related to some operations to be performed before running the docker containers, while the remaining issue is the #5: https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.XACML-Access-Rules/issues/5
The Pep Proxy seems is not able to communicate with the IdM

Comment: Actually I solved all the problems through a unique docker-compose (like the one reported in the tutorial). The final issue was related to a port conflict.
Look at the github issue for more details!
Thank you again @JasonFox for your support and availability!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a timing issue with your local set up. More specifically, it appears that the timing for `docker-compose` on your machine is not waiting for Keyrock to be available before the PEP Proxy times out.

There are multiple strategies for dealing with these issues such as adding a wait in the start-up entrypoint, adding `restart:true` within the `docker-compose` amending the infrastructure or using some third party script. A good list of strategies can be found in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y).

Comment: Thank you! Actually I solved all the problems by creating a unique docker-compose.yml file with all the components. It allows a synchronization among all the components.
For other users: you can find such a similar docker-compose from the tutorial suggested by Jason in the comments: [XACML-Access-Rules](https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.XACML-Access-Rules)